# configuring haproxy in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy

i want to know how to configure haproxy and rabbitmq.i want to make my rabbitmq more scalable and available....

any link any idea anyone have

Answer (score 1):

There is a [tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/pacemaker.html) provided by the RabbitMQ folks to do HA/Failover.
They use DRBD and Pacemaker, you can have a look at the link provided.